# Textbook on infinite loop spaces

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation, loop-spaces

I'm looking for a good update reference covering the material in first three chapters of "Adams, Infinite loop spaces" (specially construction of delooping functors and group completion) with exact definitions and complete proofs.

Thanks!